# Graphics driver not working after reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I rebooted my machine after installing some updates that Kubuntu (22.04) recommended, and now my drivers are acting up. I noticed that the refresh-rate isn't what it used to be and the graphics card isn't performing as usual (RTX 2070). I opened the additional drivers and it seemed to still have the Nvidia driver 515 selected, but it wasn't working. I tried rebooting, purging everything nvidia-related and selecting the nouveau driver, rebooting again and then selecting the latest driver (520) but it didn't do anything. When I run nvidia-smi it returns "Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch". I tried uninstalling and installing the driver from the nvidia website. It said it completed the installation, but it nvidia-smi gives the same error. Finally I tried installing an older driver (470) but the same issue persists. In the additional drivers, the driver I install is highlighted, but doesn't seem to be used.

"cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version" returns:

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  510.73.05  Sat May  7 05:30:26 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)

and "cat /sys/module/nvidia/version" returns:

510.73.05

Running nvidia-detector returns:

nvidia-driver-520

None of the questions I've found on this forum matching my issue have had solutions that resolved my issue. Installing the driver from the command-line doesn't do anything either. I'm running on X11. Please let me know if including any more information would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
The issue was only resolved until a reboot, then the same issue arose.

Solved it! After countless removals of the current driver and re-installing through both the driver-manager and the downloaded driver I did the following as found (and very slightly tweaked) here:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=154932&start=20#p847465

First I selected the nouveau driver and rebooted. Then I ran the following command:

apt install -y libc6-dev libglvnd-dev && echo "blacklist nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf && sudo update-initramfs -u

Then did a ctrl+alt+f2 and typed in:

sudo service sddm stop

followed by installing the driver with the -q option.

then sudo service sddm start

Works now! Hope anyone who is in a similar situation can use this as help. nvidia-smi returns the correct driver and all now.